# Exclude items from first-level filter when children-levels are empty at Loopback find()

Tags: angularjs, node.js, relational-database, loopbackjs, strongloop

When using **Strongloop Loopback**, we can make a data request (with relations) to the database these ways:

(1) Using lb-service (at front-end)

```
Model.find({
  filter: {
    where: {id: 1},
    include: {
      relation: 'relationship',
      scope: {where: {id: 2}}
    }
  }
}, function (instances) {
}, function (err) {
});
```

(2) Using node.js (at server-side)

```
Model.find({
  where: {id: 1},
  include: {
    relation: 'relationship',
    scope: {where: {id: 2}}
  }
}, function (err, instances) {
});
```

**What I need:** Exclude items from first filter whether another filter fails.
There is one obvious solution: filtering the response, this way:

```
instances = instances.filter(function(instance){
  return typeof(instance.relationship) !== "undefined";
});
```

**But...** Using `filter()` to eliminate is not a good scalable solution, because it will always iterate over the array. *Using this solution at the front-end is not good*, because the size of the array will slow down the performance. Bringing it to the server-side *could be a solution*. **But...** each model will have a particular set of relations... and it is not scalable again!

**Main question:** Is there some way to overcome this situation, excluding items from the first filter whether second (third, or more) fails **simultaneously (or not)**?

Something like, defining it on filter object:

```
var filter = {
  where: {id: 1},
  include: {
    relation: {name: 'relationship', required: true}, // required means this filter *needs* to be satisfied 
    scope: {where: {id: 2}}
  }
};
```

**Requirements:**

(1) *SQL query is not an option* ;)

(2) I am using MySQL as database. So things like

`{ where: { id: 1, relationship.id: 2 } }`

will not work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this within the filter syntax itself. I think you would have to [write a custom remote method](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods) to do the filtering yourself after the initial query was complete. Here's what that might look like:

```
// in /common/models/model.js

Model.filterResults = function filterResults(filter, next) {
  Model.find(filter, function doFilter(err, data) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    var filteredData = data.filter(function(model) {
      return model.otherThings && model.otherThings().length;
    });

    next(null, filteredData);
  });
};

Model.remoteMethod(
  'filterResults',
  {
    accepts: { arg: 'filter', type: 'object', http: { source: 'query' } },
    returns: { arg: 'results', type: 'array' },
    http: { verb: 'get', path: '/no-empties' }
  }
);
```

Now you can hit: `.../api/Models/no-empies?filter={"include":"otherThings"}` and you will only get back `Models` that have a related `OtherThing`. Note that this is for a one-to-many relationship, but hopefully you can see how to change it to fit your needs.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant when I said writing in server-side. But it is dependent to a specific Model. Is there anyway to "generify" this? Or include a custom parameter inside filter ... ?

Comment: Hmm... actually, it looks like you might be able to apply an application-wide remote hook, something like: `app.remotes().after('**', function(context, next) { ... })` I'm not sure what all you would need to do in there, but it's a start.

Comment: Create a BaseModel, overrwrite `find(.)`, apply `filter(.)` using filter object as reference, couldn't be a solution?